# Can't start Unity + Firebase without an internet connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unity-game-engine

So I've integrated the Firebase Unity plugin into my Unity project. I'm hitting a problem where if I'm not connected to the internet, Firebase will throw all kinds of errors when it tries to get a database reference. The following errors are called on (Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase) database.GetReference(path).

```
01/02/0001 17:46:29 [Error] WebSocket: ws_0 - could not get ip address
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String hostName) [0x00000] in <filename     unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.String hostNameOrAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Firebase.Database.Internal.TubeSock.WebSocket.GetIpAddress (System.String hostName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Firebase.FirebaseHandler:LogMessage(LogLevel, String)
Firebase.Unity.UnityLoggingService:LogMessage(LogLevel, String)
Firebase.Database.Internal.Logging.DefaultLogger:Error(String, String)
Firebase.Database.Internal.Logging.DefaultLogger:OnLogMessage(Level, String, String, Int64)
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
   YourCodeToCallFireBaseFunction(); // statements causing exception
}
catch( SocketException e1 ) //Specifically catch **SocketException**
{
   // error handling code
}
finally
{
   // statements to be executed
}
```

Comment: I found the specific line throwing the error but the try catch block won’t catch the exception. I think it’s because the exception is thrown inside Firebase’s internal library or something